# tinyalsa: pcm_start yields bad file number error

Tags: c, alsa, tinyalsa

I'm attempting a barebones program to use tinyalsa, but `pcm_start` always fails, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `9` (`EBADF`, i.e. bad file number). The call to `pcm_open` before this returns a non-null pointer, but it sets `errno` to `22`.

There appears to be no documentation for tinyalsa, so I'm having trouble understanding what I'm supposed to do. I based my program on an example from alsa (not tinyalsa), and I've read the header files for tinyalsa. Can anyone provide any guidance?

```c
pcm * dev = pcm_open(1, 0, PCM_OUT, &config);
if (err = pcm_start(dev)) printf("err: %d\t errno: %d\n", err, errno);
```

*(Full code available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dpRRq3Aq).)*

I infer the values for the first two arguments of `pcm_open` from `aplay --list-devices`, which outputs:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

*(I am compiling and running this on my workstation, not on an Android.)*

Comment: Obviously `pcm_open` failed. For a reason,  print `dev->error`.

Comment: Thanks @user58697 . The message is `cannot set hw params: Invalid argument`. If I were using regular alsa, I'd use the 'plugin' layer, but that appears not to be an option here, so I still don't know what I need to change.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the maintainers for the TinyALSA project.

You should error check that code of yours.

This is how you would correctly check for a failure with the PCM structure:

```
dev = pcm_open(1, 0, PCM_OUT, &config);
if (dev == NULL) {
    /* memory allocation failure */
} else if (!pcm_is_ready(pcm)){
    printf("error: pcm_open: %s\n", pcm_get_error(pcm));
}
```

And that should tell you why TinyALSA could not open your device.

If that doesn't help debug your problem, submit an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/issues/new) and include a link to the code, the error message after `pcm_open`, and a list of the directory contents in `/dev/snd`.

Also, the documentation on the API is definitely a work in progress. I included the bit about error checking `pcm_open` in the master branch. If you need further clarification on something, please create an issue for it!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I wish I recalled what was going on here. I do have tinyalsa working now.

Comment: @JellicleCat, the problem in your code I saw from pastebin is your period size and period count. If I recall correctly, we have a program called tinypcminfo that helps determine what the valid parameters are. Usually 1024 it's okay for period size, and 4 is good enough for period count. But that depends on what you're doing with the audio.

Comment: is there any mechanism tinyalsa provide to dump the raw data into a file? like alsa-lib provides file plugin to dump the data into a file.

Comment: @VishalGupta, yes. You can use `tinycap` and use the `--` option to record raw samples to the standard output. Then just redirect the standard output to the file you want to put the samples into. For example, `tinycap -t 3 -- >audio.raw`.

Comment: @tay10r sorry my question might be not clear. I looking for something similar like "file plugin" of alsa.

at the time when I am doing tinyplay then tinyplay will dump the data into a file as well when it writes the data to PCM.

one way I found by modifying the pcm.c file.

but with alsa lib we can do this by creating .asoundrc and creating a file plugin so when we do aplay it also dumps the data into file when it writes to PCM device.

Comment: @VishalGupta currently that kind of plugin system isn't supported. There's only so much you can add to a library and still consider it minimalistic. If you have any other questions or want to continue the discussion, please create an issue at https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa

Answer (score 0):

Now looking at [pcm.c](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/blob/master/src/pcm.c), the `cannot set hw params` message comes from line 865,

```
    if (ioctl(pcm->fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_PARAMS, &params)) {
```

`params` are initialized from `config`. At this place I have no say. My best recommendation is to step `pcm_open` in a debugger and see what it thinks about `params`.